# GXT: unicode regex works in debug, but not in production

Tags: regex, gwt, unicode, gxt

i am using GXT 2.1.1 and GWT 2.0.3. i created a Unicode regex expression, and then set it via TextBundle().setRegEx() function. it works like a charm in debug mode, but not in production.

my goal is to only allow either alphanumeric values, or numeric values only that can also be negative. when i use ASCII expression such as:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(\-?[0-9]+))$
```

it works in both debug and production modes. but when switching to Unicode expression:

```
^(([\pL\pN]+)|(\-?[\pN]+))$
```

it only works in debug.

i am really stuck and would greatly appreciate any help. thank you!!!

Comment: Please edit your question to add more info: what is your regex? What input are you using it on in both cases?

Comment: right you are, Robin. i have adjusted my original post with the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that JavaScript does not support Unicode shortcut/character-classes natively (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode) and [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html)).

Just stick with the first version or use [valid character classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes).

Comment: while i do appreciate your response, are you telling me that there is no Unicode regex support for GXT and/or javascript?

Comment: Yes: no native support in js. GWT is no different since the implementation of the `RegExp` class (starting from GWT 2.1) is based on the `RegExp` js object (which is different from the Java one: check the doc I linked). Before GWT 2.1, there is only JSNI. Can't say for GXT but I hardly think so (and your issue is a clear clue).